# Dependent selects with Chosen Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen, prototype-chosen

I just want to do something very simple, which is a select depending on which option is selected it populates a second select.

I've always done this by hiding/showing selects this way (JS):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
$("#select_1").change(function() {
        if ($("#select_1").val()=="A") {
        $("#select_2").show();
        $("#select_3").hide(); 
    }

    else if ($("#select_1").val()=="B") {
        $("#select_3").show();
        $("#select_2").hide();
    };
});
```

But now I'm trying Chosen and it does not work. It removes all Chosen mask and returns the selects to native. I've also tried this (JS):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $("#select_2").css('visibility','hidden');
  $(".chosen").chosen();
  $("#select_1").click(function() {
   if ($("#select_1").val()=="A") {
   $("#select_2").css('visibility','visible');

   }
```

And it doesn't work either. It does not remove the Chosen, but doesn't do anything. Any idea on this? I know it sounds pretty basic by I couldn't find an accurate response to it anywhere.

PS: I'm trying to do it with JS, not via AJAX.

Comment: Is there a plugin that you're using for the chosen() function? If so, are you including it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that #select_1 is to have the chosen plugin applied to it. If this is correct, #select_1 is going to have a style of display:none; applied to it, so you not going to register any 'click' events on it.

If you look at the "chosen" documentation, http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/, you can discover how to register a change handler to your chosen element.

If chosen is applied to #select_2 and #select_3, then toggling the visibility of these two elements is pointless because they are already hidden. The HTML rendered by the chosen plugin will have container elements with IDs of #select_2_chosen and #select_3_chosen - so toggle the visibility of these!

The code below assumes that #select_2 and #select_3 have the class 'chosen'. I am applying the chosen to #select_1 separately so I can bind the change event that is to be unique to it. Finally, I trigger the change event immediately after defining the change handler so that #select_3_chosen will become hidden.

```
$(".chosen").chosen();
$("#select_1").chosen().change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value=="A") {
        $("#select_2_chosen").css('visibility','visible');
        $("#select_3_chosen").css('visibility','hidden');
    } else if (value == "B") {
        $("#select_2_chosen").css('visibility','hidden');
        $("#select_3_chosen").css('visibility','visible');
    } 
}).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However, not with .css('visibility','hidden') but with .hide()